180hz + 60hz dual monitor setup, my 180hz monitor is being capped at 60hz
(Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS GNOME) The cursor is being ran at 180hz but everything else (windows, games, etc) are being capped at 60hz. Almost as like its running Vsync on every single game with 60hz causing crazy input lag in games. I've tried multiple solutions which havent worked. I am using a GTX 980. I've also tried using wayland which did fix the problem but gave me problems when using wine/proton on specific games.

In your settings, Gnome settings > Displays, what's the Refresh Rate ? Are you able to change it ?

I am able to, but everything just gets ran at 60hz unless i unplug my other monitor.
